# counting jquery script tags with xpath

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, xpath, greasemonkey

I want to use a document.evaluate expression in a userscript to be able to detect the presence (or absence) of an existing jQuery library in the document head, as part of developing a jQuery wrapper for userscripts that will work in firefox and chrome, and will not conflict with other libraries (what i'm hoping to do is get it to insert the library and any jquery code, if necessary, before any other script tags and have them run in no conflict mode.)

Long story short, this statement does not appear to work:

```
jqueryscript = document.evaluate("//*script[contains(@src, 'jquery')]", document.head, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

when I try to test if  jqueryscript.snapshotLength > 0, the script fails. I am incredibly new at xpath so please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

```
jqueryscript = document.evaluate ("//script[contains (@src, 'jquery')]", document.head, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

should work.

But note that on some sites (like SO) it will yield false hits.
EG:

```
<script ... src="http://engine2.adzerk.net/z/8277/adzerk2_2_17_45?keywords=jquery,firefox,google-chrome,xpath,greasemonkey,x-user-registered,x-5000plus-rep">
```

So,

```
jqueryscript = document.evaluate ("//script[contains (@src, '/jquery')]", document.head, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

might be better.